# Parameter passing with initWithNibName:

Tags: iphone, parameter-passing

In iphone Application
I need to pass some values to a new viewcontroller object while it create from a method in another viewcontroller class so I can initialize that values in (id)initWithNibName:method of new viewcontroller then I can load those values in viewdidLoad method.

what I want to know is how do I pass the values(parameters) to the constructor(initWithNibName) of a new viewcontrollor Object like constructor overloading in java
give me some code example just showing how initWithNibName called with extra parameters and how to retrieve them in the newly created object 
Thanks...

---

Answer

---

this is the way I solve the problem "Observation is a object with attributes"
in ViewControllor.h I put

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil set:(Observation *)observation;
```

in ViewControllor.m file I put

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil set:(Observation *)observation{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization on passed parameter observation object         
    draftObservation = observation;
}
return self;
```

}

then I call it this way in another class

```
 ObsevationListView *obsevationListView = [[ObservationViewControllor alloc]  
                                          initWithNibName:@"ObservationViewControllor" 
                                          bundle:nil set:observer];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obsevationListView animated:YES];
```

it works fine. I'm glad if anyone get help from this

Comment: Very Very nice... I exactly wanted this... Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 8):

You should create another initializer in your class, something like

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andParam:(id)aParam {
...
self.param = aParam;
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to declare that initializer in your .h (upvotted)

Comment: Also your first line in side that initializer should be: `self = [self initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];` for proper initialization.

Comment: Thanks guys I did it with your help. create another initializer and passed object with data and load that data to fields in viewDidLoad method

Comment: Probably obvious but the last line in that initializer should be `return self;`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to have a property for that parameter and set it either before or after you call using the following code:

`initWithNibName:bundle:`