# How to pass object as a parameter to new class constructor in objective c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, class

I'm pretty new with objective c. 
I have instantiated 'myClass' object in ViewController.m file.

```
MyClass myClass = [[MyClass alloc]init];
```

I have to pass this 'myClass' object to new class constructor(say Person class) as a parameter.

How could I implement this and use same 'myClass' object in Person class?

Thanks.

Comment: the same question is asked here please look at this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248944/parameter-passing-with-initwithnibname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instantiated like below

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc]init];
```

in your Person class declare a variable,

```
MyClass *class;
```

create method,

```
- (id) initWithClass:(MyClass *)myClass{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.class= myClass;
    }    
    return self;
}
```

initialize the person class as

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithClass:myClass];
```

Answer (score 0):

in your person class, make method like this

```
- (id) initWithMyClass:(MyClass *)m{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.myclass= m;
    }    
    return self;
}
```

now you can call it like

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithMyClass:myClass];//using your variable here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an `initWithXXX` method like this:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

- (id)initWithMyClass:(MyClass *)myClass;

@end
```